# How to compute $\sum_{r=0}^N \frac{N!}{(N-r)!}$? This quantity is the count of $r$-permutations of $N$ items (for $r$ ranging from $0$ to $N$).

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, factorial

Given $N$ items, how many $r$-permutations are there (for $r$ ranging from $0$ to $N$)?

0. There is $1$ $0$-permutation (the empty permutation).
1. There are $N$ $1$-permutations.
2. There are $N(N-1)$ $2$-permutations.
3. There are $N(N-1)(N-2)$ $3$-permutations.

...

$r$. There are $\frac{N!}{(N-r)!}$ $r$-permutations.

...

$N$. There are $N!$ $N$-permutations.

---

So, the number of $r$-permutations of $N$ items is

$$
S(N) = \sum_{r=0}^N \frac{N!}{(N-r)!} = 1 + N + N(N-1) + N(N-1)(N-2) + ... + N!
$$

Is there a way to simplify this to simpler terms? My only attack is that

$$S(N) = 1 + N \cdot S(N-1)$$

with

$$S(0) = 1$$

which is very close to the factorial recurrence relation $F(N) = N \cdot F(N-1)$ with $F(0) = 1$, but not quite because of the $1 +$ in $S(N) = 1 + N \cdot S(N-1)$.

---

I'm aware that

$$
\sum_{r=0}^N \frac{N!}{r!(N-r)!} = \sum_{r=0}^N \binom{N}{r} = 2^N
$$

from counting subsets of $N$ distinct items, but not sure if this can be used to solve the other summation.

---

Could a generating function approach work here?

Comment: Since $N$ is a constant, it seems that your problem reduces to simplifying the expression $~\displaystyle \left[\sum_{k=0}^N ~\frac{1}{k!}\right], ~$ which is simply a partial sum of the Taylor expansion of $~e^x~$ at $~x = 1.~$  I am unaware of any corresponding simplification of such a partial sum.

Comment: In the OEIS this is https://oeis.org/A000522 .  That entry gives the formula $S(n) = \lfloor e \times n! \rfloor$.  I believe this can be shown by noting that: 
(1) $S(n)$ is an integer
(2) $e \times n! - S(n) = n! / (n+1)! + n! / (n+2)! + n! / (n+3)! + \cdots$ is between 0 and 1.  I don't believe there's any way to get there from the recurrence, though, which is what @joseville is asking for.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Thanks! If you write that as an answer I'll accept it as it's a closed form of $S(n)$, which is what I was looking for. The intuition for why that's the closed form is appreciated as well.