# Number of implementations of a boolean function taking into account necessary, sufficient, and necessary and sufficient conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, boolean

Suppose we wanted to implement a boolean function, such as `isRectangle`, by making note of its necessary, sufficient, and necessary and sufficient conditions and combining them in different ways. How many unique implementations can we make?

For the example of `isRectangle`, we have

Let $P = $ "shape $s$ is a rectangle"

$N$: Necessary condition of $P$ (i.e. $P \rightarrow N$)

- $N_1 = $ shape $s$ has four sides
- $N_2 = $ shape $s$ has four angles

$S$: Sufficient condition for $P$ (i.e. $S \rightarrow P$)

- $S_1 = $ shape $s$ is a square

$T$: Necessary and sufficient conditions (i.e. $P \leftrightarrow T$)

- $T_1 = $ shape $s$ has four angles and they are all right angles

One implementation of `isRectangle` would be:

```
def isRectangle(s):
  if not N1: return False
  if not N2: return False
  if S1: return True
  return T1
```

but this is just one of many. A second could be:

```
def isRectangle(s):
  if S1: return True
  if not N2: return False
  return T1
```

And yet a third could be

```
def isRectangle(s):
  return T1
```

---

In general, how many implementations are there of a boolean function, when taking into account necessary conditions, sufficient conditions, and necessary and sufficient conditions?

Answer (score 1):

---

In general, for a given proposition $P$,

- Let $N$ be the set of necessary, but not sufficient, conditions of $P$, that is, $N = \{C\ |\ P \rightarrow C\ \wedge\ C \not\rightarrow P\}$.
- Let $S$ be the set of sufficient, but not necessary, conditions for $P$, that is $S = \{C\ |\ C \rightarrow P\ \wedge\ P \not\rightarrow C \}$.
- Let $T$ be the set of necessary and sufficient conditions for $P$, that is, $T = \{C\ |\ P \leftrightarrow C\}$.

Necessary and Sufficient conditions allow us to do early returns

- Early return False: if any $N$ condition is false, then $P$ is false.
- Early return True: if any $S$ condition is true, the $P$ is true.

We can implement $P$ as any of the following

```
def isP(input):
  NS_early_return*
  T_return
```

where

```
NS_early_return := N_early_return | S_early_return
N_early_return := "if not n: return False"
S_early_return := "if s: return True"
T_return := return t
```

where `n` $\in N$, `s` $\in S$, and `t` $\in T$.

Now, to count the number of implementations of this boolean function,

- Let $|N|$ be the count of necessary, but not sufficient, conditions
- Let $|S|$ be the count of sufficient, but not necessary, conditions
- Let $|T|$ be the count of necessary and sufficient conditions

Then any $r$-permutation of $N$ and $S$ conditions (with $r$ ranging from $0$ to $|N| + |S|$) followed by a $T$ condition form an implementation.

The total number of implementations, then$^1$, is $\bigg\lfloor e \cdot \big(|N|+|S|\big)! \bigg\rfloor\ \cdot |T|$

---

$^1$: See [How to compute $\sum_{r=0}^N \frac{N!}{(N-r)!}$? This quantity is the count of $r$-permutations of $N$ items (for $r$ ranging from $0$ to $N$).](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4651405/833760)

---

Why check a necessary condition or a sufficient condition when all we need to do is check a necessary and sufficient condition?
A: In some cases, a $N$ (necessary) condition) or a $S$ (sufficient) condition is easy(ier) to check than a $T$ (necessary and sufficient) condition and if the $N$ condition fails, we can return `False` early, or if the $S$ condition succeeds, we can return `True` early w/o having to check a more expensive $T$ condition.